# Winforms Checkbox : CheckState property Indeterminate renders differently

Tags: winforms, checkbox, state, checked

In C# environment, setting a checkbox's CheckState property to Indeterminate displays a "green square" inside the checkbox.

In VB environment, this displays as a "grayed out check" (which is less intuitive, even for "dummy" users).

How do i make Indeterminate state look like a "green square" in VB.NET ?

Btw, i am using VS2008, Winforms 2.0.

(Btw2: I tried to create two tags CheckState Indeterminate, which is more appropriate to my question, but disallowed by StackOverflow due to points!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable XP visual styles for your application to get the green square. Try this in your `Main` function before calling `Application.Run(...)`:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Comment: HOWEVER i cannot use it because the Toolbar in my MDI parent form doesn't display any images! Googling told me to use Application.DoEvents() but that didn't do anything for me:-( 
Next step is to use "manifests" whatever that means.. have to look it up.

Comment: I had a similar situation and just gave up on indeterminate checkboxes